# PHP is commenting out my HTML IDs?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. It is commenting out my code when it hits an ID tag. How can I override this? Thanks.

```
<?php echo "<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact" class="contact-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h4 style="font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:0;">Begin Your Partnership with Us and Compare <i>ALL</i> of your Business Funding Options</h4>
                <a href="#scroll-ref" class="page-scroll btn btn-success"><i>Get Started with the Quick Quote Process Now!</i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>";
?>
```

Comment: You're not escaping your quotes properly. You may want to look into heredoc syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: It's not "commenting it out".  You have `"` inside `"`, so it thinks your string ended.

Comment: Why are you using PHP to echo this block of HTML, why not just put the HTML in the file *without* an `echo`?

Comment: Because I want to easily include it in other pages.

Comment: If you have a block of HTML you want to include in other pages, you can create a file with that HTML in it (no PHP) and `include` it in your PHP pages when you need it.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either heredoc syntax:

```
<?php echo <<<HTML
<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact" class="contact-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h4>Begin Your Partnership with Us and Compare <i>ALL</i> of your Business Funding Options</h4>
                <a href="#scroll-ref" class="page-scroll btn btn-success"><i>Get Started with the Quick Quote Process Now!</i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
HTML;
?>
```

... single quotes for the `echo` statement:

```
<?php echo '
<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact" class="contact-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h4>Begin Your Partnership with Us and Compare <i>ALL</i> of your Business Funding Options</h4>
                <a href="#scroll-ref" class="page-scroll btn btn-success"><i>Get Started with the Quick Quote Process Now!</i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
';
?>
```

... or place the HTML code outside of PHP:

```
<?php
// PHP code
?>
<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact" class="contact-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h4>Begin Your Partnership with Us and Compare <i>ALL</i> of your Business Funding Options</h4>
                <a href="#scroll-ref" class="page-scroll btn btn-success"><i>Get Started with the Quick Quote Process Now!</i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php
// More PHP code
?>
```

There are a few other options besides these, but they are usually not very readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for your attributes since you're using double quotes for your echo string.

#### EXPLANATION

Essentially you're terminating your `echo` statement after `<section id=` because you used the same quote for the attribute value.

You have two options:

1. Escape the double quotes inside your string `\"contact\"`
2. Just use singe quotes `'contact'`

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Why would you use single quotes in HTML? You want to use single quotes for the `echo` statement instead.

Comment: @Midas I believe they get converted to double quotes anyway? Also, is there a problem with using single quotes in HTML?

Comment: You can but it looks ugly and it clashes with Javascript, where single quotes are most common: `<a onclick="alert('blah')">`

Comment: @Midas They are interchangeable. You are expressing a personal preference, not a coding issue.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio They will not be converted in the output

Comment: @chris85 Try to find me a website that uses single quotes, then? :)

Comment: @Midas Just one? http://www.yahoo.com They even interchange there, `<meta property="og:type" content='website' />`.

Comment: @chris85 Just open an average HTML book and it will tell you to use double quotes. It's just for convention. I hoped this was common sense :/

Comment: @Midas Possibly, I haven't read an HTML book in a while. They are interchangeable though and there is nothing wrong with using them. The rendering will happen the same as long as it is consistent (e.g. `id="Terrible'` will never work, or `name='O'brien'` (which is what OP did here (well inverted))). Going too long in comments though.

Comment: Downvote because of personal preference. LOL!